# How to log gRPC error details in ServerInterceptor

Tags: grpc-java

I have written one grpc server interceptor in java language to log request and response of every RPC. I am logging request inside 'onMessage(ReqT message)' method and logging response inside 'sendMessage(RespT message)' method. I would like to know incase of grpc errors, where should I catch them and log. And in this case does the trigger goes to sendMessage() method or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServerCall.close()` is the method the stub uses to pass the error details. The status will be OK if the RPC succeeded. Whether the error information is actually used can be detected via `ServerCall.Listener.onCancel()` and `ServerCall.Listener.onComplete()`. If an error happens within gRPC, gRPC will cancel the RPC, so `onCancel()` will be called.

```java
class LoggingServerCall extends SimpleForwardingServerCall {
  private Status status;
  private Metadata trailers;

  public LoggingServerCall(ServerCall call) {
    super(call);
  }
  
  public void wrapListener(ServerCall.Listener delegate) {
    return new LoggingListener(delegate);
  }
  
  @Override public void close(Status status, Metadata trailers) {
    // It would be fine to log here and not save any information, but
    // viewers of the logs must realize that if onCancel() is called,
    // then this information was not used.
    // log("Application closed RPC", status, trailers);
    this.status = status;
    // Metadata is mutable and not thread-safe, so make a copy
    this.trailers = new Metadata();
    this.trailers.merge(trailers);
    super.close(status, trailers);
  }

  private class LoggingListener extends SimpleForwardingServerCallListener {
    public LoggingListener(ServerCall.Listener delegate) {
      super(delegate);
    }

    @Override public void onCancel() {
      log("RPC cancelled");
    }

    @Override public void onComplete() {
      log("RPC complete", status, trailers);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Eric Anderson mentioned, I tried to implement close() method and I am able to catch grpc errors there. Thanks to Eric Anderson.

```
@Override
        public void close(Status status, Metadata trailers) {
            System.out.println("close() called");
            if(!status.isOk()) {
                System.out.println("Exception occurred");
                System.out.println(status.asException().getMessage());
                System.out.println(status.asException().getLocalizedMessage());
                System.out.println(status.getCode());
            }
             super.close(status, trailers); 
         }
```